# Using git-remote-dropbox with Intellij IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-remote

I want to use [git-remote-dropbox](https://github.com/anishathalye/git-remote-dropbox) as a git remote.

How do I have to set it up in Intellij IDEA?

If I use `dropbox://path/to/repo` in the menu topic `File` `Settings Repository`, I get an error message:

```
URI not supported: dropbox://path/to/repo
```

Answer (score 0):

Settings repository feature uses JGit implementation, which does not support the mentioned extension for git. Please note that Settings repository is not the repository for your project source code. It is a separate feature.

If you want to use dropbox as a repository for your IDE settings, you are welcome to submit a feature request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues

The workaround here will be to specify your local Dropbox folder as a Settings repository.

However, if you want to use Dropbox as a remote for your project source code, it should work, based on the extension description, unless there is something specific it does to git which will conflict with the way IDEA uses it.

In the project with enabled Git integration, go to **VCS - Git - Remotes...** and try adding the remote there.